# GoogleSheet Facing Formatting Issues while Sending Email of Range copied to Email Body

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a atomized email report pasted in Gmail body and sending emails. All things working good expect the format on email Body is showing like Image 1.

Last column is only the time gap difference which is formatted on Google Sheet as Duration - HH:MM:SS

How data is Being reflected in Email body:
[image]

Actual Image from Google Sheet - From where Email is being Generated:
[image]

**Script for Sending emails & Fetching data:**

```
  var stockData = getData();
  var body = getEmailText(stockData);
  var htmlBody = getEmailHtml(stockData); 
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "email@email.com",
    subject: "Operations - Today's Job Details",
    body: body,
    htmlBody: htmlBody
  });
}
function getEmailText(stockData) {
  var text = "";
  stockData.forEach(function(stock) {
    text = text + stock.name + "\n" + stock.ticker + "\n" + stock.price + "\n-----------------------\n\n";
  });
  return text;
}
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
function getData() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Email").getRange("Stocks").getValues();
  values.shift(); //remove headers
  var stocks = [];
  values.forEach(function(value) {
    var stock = {};
    stock.sr = value[0];
    stock.job = value[1];
    stock.work = value[2];
    stock.worked = value[3];
    stock.time = value[4];
    stocks.push(stock);
  })
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(stocks));
  return stocks;
}
```

**Followed by Html code:**

```
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" dir="ltr" border="1" style="table-layout:fixed;font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial;width:0px;border-collapse:collapse;border:none">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="45">
                <col width="588">
                    <col width="57">
                        <col width="90">
                            <col width="103">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr style="height:21px">
                <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:middle;background-color:rgb(252,229,205);font-weight:bold;text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">SR</td>
                <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:middle;background-color:rgb(252,229,205);font-weight:bold;text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">JOB DETAIL</td>
                <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:middle;background-color:rgb(252,229,205);font-weight:bold;text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">WORK TODAY?</td>
                <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:middle;background-color:rgb(252,229,205);font-weight:bold;text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">WORKED X TIMES</td>
                <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:middle;background-color:rgb(252,229,205);font-weight:bold;text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)">TIME SPENT ON JOB</td>
            </tr>
            <? for(var i = 0; i < stocks.length; i++) { ?>
            <tr style="height:21px">
                <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)"><?= stocks[i].sr ?></td>
                <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)"><?= stocks[i].job ?></td>
                <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)"><?= stocks[i].work ?></td>
                <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)"><?= stocks[i].worked ?></td>
                <td style="overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;text-align:center;border:1px solid rgb(204,204,204)"><?= stocks[i].time ?></td>
            </tr>
            <? } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Change:**

```
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Email").getRange("Stocks").getValues();
```

**to:**

```
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Email").getRange("Stocks").getDisplayValues();
```

to get the date as it is displayed in the sheet.

Comment: Thank you! Solved the Problem...

Can you also tell me, if the cell is COLORED, in same sheet how i can get same in Gmail email body?

Comment: @AtifQayyum could you please post a separate question regarding that so other readers can also contribute to the answer. Thanks a lot and sorry for the incovenience.