# Need to copy Cell Color and Send in EMAIL Body

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My Sheet cell colors are changed automatically based on results values. Need to Send Send this data range in email Body... Code is running good, but do not pick colors of cells as displayed in below image. Help me set the code to copy and send body email as the data shown below.

**Actual Sheet Display:**

[image]

Here is the script code copying data from Google Sheet and Sending to email Body (using an html template) you can view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66589934/googlesheet-facing-formatting-issues-while-sending-email-of-range-copied-to-emai/66590695#66590695).

```
function getEmailHtml(stockData) {
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Template.html");
  htmlTemplate.stocks = stockData;
  var htmlBody = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  return htmlBody;
}
function sendEmail() {
  var stockData = getData();
  var body = getEmailText(stockData);
  var htmlBody = getEmailHtml(stockData); 
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "email@email.com",
    subject: "Operations - Today's Job Details",
    body: body,
    htmlBody: htmlBody
  });
}
function getEmailText(stockData) {
  var text = "";
  stockData.forEach(function(stock) {
    text = text + stock.name + "\n" + stock.ticker + "\n" + stock.price + "\n-----------------------\n\n";
  });
  return text;
}
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
function getData() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Email").getRange("Stocks").getDisplayValues();
  values.shift(); //remove headers
  var stocks = [];
  values.forEach(function(value) {
    var stock = {};
    stock.sr = value[0];
    stock.job = value[1];
    stock.work = value[2];
    stock.worked = value[3];
    stock.time = value[4];
    stocks.push(stock);
  })
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(stocks));
  return stocks;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to set the background color of the rows of Spreadsheet to the rows of HTML table.
- In your Spreadsheet, each row has one background color.

In this case, I would like to propose to retrieve the background colors of each row of the Spreadsheet, and those are set to the value of `style` of `tr` using the template. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify the function of `getEmailHtml` of Google Apps Script as follows.

```
function getEmailHtml(stockData) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Email").getRange("Stocks");
  var colors = range.getBackgrounds().map(([a]) => a);
  colors.shift();
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Template.html");
  htmlTemplate.stocks = stockData;
  htmlTemplate.colors = colors;
  var htmlBody = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  return htmlBody;
}
```

And also, please modify your HTML template as follows.

From:

```
<? for(var i = 0; i < stocks.length; i++) { ?>
<tr style="height:21px">
```

To:

```
<? for(var i = 0; i < stocks.length; i++) { ?>
<tr style="height:21px;background-color:<?= colors[i] ?>;">
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, the background colors are retrieved from the 1st column of your range of `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Email").getRange("Stocks")`. When you want to change this, please modify above script.

#### Reference:

- [getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds)

Comment: Thank you very much for Helping :-)

Comment: @Atif Qayyum Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.